# ELAN Touchpad not working

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I was using my touchpad just fine for quite a while (months), and one day I simply turned on my laptop and it no longer functions. I tried messing with input drivers, and I've found out if I remove `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`, and install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`, the touchpad will work, but then I can't use my keyboard. If I install libinput after that, the touchpad no longer works.

(When I say does not work, I mean the touchpad does not respond to any sort of activity at all.)

Output of `xinput` (with only libinput installed):

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN2513:00 04F3:2B55                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wide Vision HD Camera: HP Wi           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ELAN2513:00 04F3:2B55 Stylus              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```